# PHP - Composer alternative

Tags: php, package-manager

I previously used `npm` and `composer` to manage all of my packages.
I recently change `npm` to `pnpm` who use a shared folders and symlinks.
https://pnpm.js.org/

I'd like to know if there is something like this for my `composer`'s `vendor` folder.

Comment: why you want to use some other then composer or npm? just curious

Comment: I've many projects on my computer, using almost the same dependencies. With `pnpm`, each version of each package is downloaded only once, and not for each project.